# What term has suddenly replaced the term "physically challenged" from 1996?

Tags: synonyms

Why has the term "physically challenged" been used less and less since 1996-97 ([ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentally%20challenged,physically%20challenged&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)), while the term "mentally challenged" continues to have a positive trend?

What term has gradually replaced the term "physically challenged" since 1996?

[image]

Comment: handicapped?  http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/handicap

Comment: No its probably not handicapped.  I bet it is "disabled."  http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disabled

Comment: Maybe [*special needs.*](https://www.google.com/#q=special+needs+)

Comment: I don't think the drop is as precipitous as that graph might indicate. Those are small numbers. As @Lumberjack said, [disabled](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentally+challenged%2Cphysically+challenged%2Cphysically+disabled%2Cphysically+handicapped&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seems to be a more preferred term. JLG's [special needs](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentally+challenged%2Cphysically+challenged%2Cphysically+disabled%2Cphysically+handicapped%2C+special+needs&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), too.

Answer (score 6):

Probably *disabled*:

- US English

  [image]
- UK English

  [image]

This is especially clear in the BrEn image where it looks like the rise of *disabled* corresponds perfectly with the fall of *handicapped*. I added *crippled* for the historical perspective.

This becomes even clearer if we use a phrase that ensures that the words are used in the relevant context:

[image]

Comment: Once upon a time it was just *crippled*, but that one got caught up in the euphemism treadmill of time.

Answer (score -2):

The term has changed. Now it is "DIFFERENTLY ABLED". Means, their ability to do things are in a different way.